# opencv java 'No such file or directory' after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, java, eclipse, opencv

I recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS.  I have been working on a java application on this machine for months, which does image processing using opencv. I compiled opencv from source.  I do my development in eclipse and link to the static opencv library that I compiled under 14.04.  As I said, this has worked for months.  Now immediately after the upgrade to 16.04, the first time I try to run it, with the same code, I get the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError /home/pwarner/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/build/lib/libopencv_java300.so: libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

here is the code:

```
public class NativeOpenCVLoader {

    static {

        System.load("/home/pwarner/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/build/lib/libopencv_java300.so");
    }
}
```

Of course, the path is correct and the file is there.

```
ls /home/pwarner/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/build/lib/libopencv_java300.so 
/home/pwarner/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/build/lib/libopencv_java300.so
```

Is there a c++ library that has changed with the upgrade so it cannot any longer read the file?  Do I need to rebuild opencv?

locate libIlmImf.so.6 gives no results.

```
pwarner@pwarner-Studio-XPS-7100:~$ locate libIlmImf.so.6
pwarner@pwarner-Studio-XPS-7100:~$
```

BUT, it seems I have libIlmImf.so

```
pwarner@pwarner-Studio-XPS-7100:/usr/lib$ locate libIlmImf.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
```

which is a softlink to:

```
pwarner@pwarner-Studio-XPS-7100:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ll libIlmImf.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Apr 17 20:42 libIlmImf.so -> libIlmImf-2_2.so.22.0.0
```

I made the softlink to libIlmImf.so.6, as suggested below by Zanna (and SahibPrime).

```
pwarner@pwarner-Studio-XPS-7100:~$ locate libIlmImf.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so.6
```

But still no luck - still getting the same UnsatisfiedLinkError error.

Comment: Can you run the command "locate libIlmImf.so.6" and add what you get to your question?

Comment: What if you make another symlink: `cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and then `sudo ln -s libIlmImf-2_2.so.22.0.0 libIlmImf.so.6`

Comment: Thanks, Zanna and SahibPrime - I made the softlink, but no luck.  I am still getting the same UnsatisfiedLinkError, 'No such file or directory'.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up spending the 3 hours to rebuild opencv from source after the upgrade to 16.04.  Now I can run the tomcat server for my project again.  I followed the excellent directions here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hd8FFw0B0uA

and here:

http://embedonix.com/articles/image-processing/installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-ubuntu/

I had two problems during make, and I had to add/tweak the directions from đàm văn tài in the youtube link above.  The make process could not find libvpx.so.1 and fell over.  I found libvpx.so.3 on my system, and took a chance and made a softlink to libvpx.so.1 from it.  The install seems happy.

The second problem appeared in relation to libtiff, and at

http://answers.opencv.org/question/35642/libtiff_40-link-errors/

I found an answer:

```
add -D BUILD_TIFF=ON
```

to the cmake list.  That fixed that problem.

I was careful to uninstall my old opencv 3.0.0 installation before installing the new 3.1.0 version.  And I can point out, that based on my experience, one is better off deleting the entire contents of the build directory if you have a problem during make, and, after fixing your problem, run cmake again, and then make.

Here are the clear, detailed steps from đàm văn tài from his youtube page (if you use them, you could head over to his page and click 'like' -- the link once again: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hd8FFw0B0uA).

```
*Update Repositories
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade

*Build tools
sudo apt install build-essential cmake 

*Multimedia"
 sudo apt install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libgdal-dev zlib1g-dev libwebp-dev  libv4l-dev libxine2-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev x264 libx264-dev yasm libxvidcore-dev libvorbis-dev libtheora-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libdc1394-22-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libfaac-dev ffmpeg

*Parallel frameworks
sudo apt install libtbb2 libtbb2-dbg libtbb-dev libpomp2-dev

*Python Support
sudo apt install python-dev python-tk python-numpy python3-dev python3-tk python3-numpy

*Oracle JDK
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt install ant  

*Extras
sudo apt install libeigen3-dev doxygen libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev mesa-common-dev qt5-default libatlas-base-dev gfortran

cd opencv-3.1.0
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-master/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
sudo apt-get install ant default-jdk
make -j2
sudo make install
sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'
sudo ldconfig
cd ..
cd samples/
cmake .
sudo make -j4
```

Comment: I thought you would probably have to do that. Thanks for the detailed answer :)